# Why am I getting invalid memory access though the correct structure has been specified?

Tags: java, c, jna

I am calling a C DLL method from Java. I have used JNA. But I am getting the following exception when I call the method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:415)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at com.kube.rfid.RFIDMain.main(RFIDMain.java:31)
```

Below is my C function.

```
RFIDLIB_API ipj_error start(
    ipj_iri_device* iri_device       /*[in]*/,
    ipj_action      action           /*[in]*/)
{
    return ipj_start(iri_device, action);
}
```

Given below is the ipj_iri_device structure

```
typedef struct _ipj_iri_device
{
    IPJ_READER_CONTEXT    reader_context;
    IPJ_READER_IDENTIFIER reader_identifier;
    uint32_t              receive_timeout_ms;

    /* Internal Only */
    uint8_t               sync_state;
    bool                  wait_for_response;
    uint32_t              frame_length;
    uint32_t              receive_index;
    uint8_t               receive_buffer[IPJ_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE];

#if !defined(IRI_RX_ONLY)
    uint8_t               transmit_buffer[IPJ_TRANSMIT_BUFFER_SIZE];
#endif

} ipj_iri_device;
```

Below is how ipj_action has been defined in C

```
typedef uint32_t ipj_action;
```

The relevant structure has been defined in JAva in the following manner.

```
public class ipj_iri_device extends Structure {

    private static final int IPJ_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
    private static final int IPJ_TRANSMIT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

    public Pointer reader_context;
    public Pointer reader_identifier;
    public int receive_timeout_ms;
    /* Internal Only */
    public byte sync_state;
    public byte wait_for_response;
    public int frame_length;
    public int receive_index;
    public byte[] receive_buffer = new byte[IPJ_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    public byte[] transmit_buffer = new byte[IPJ_TRANSMIT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("reader_context", "reader_identifier", "receive_timeout_ms", "sync_state","wait_for_response", "frame_length","receive_index","receive_buffer","transmit_buffer");
    }
}
```

The main java class looks like this.

```
public class RFIDMain {

    public  rfidlib rlib;
    public  ipj_iri_device ipj_iri_device;
    public  ipj_action ipj_action;
    public  ipj_error errorStatus;
    public  ipj_connection_params connection_params;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //ByteBuffer iriDeviceBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1000);
        //ByteBuffer actionBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1000);
        //IntByReference value = new IntByReference();
        //int ipj_key = 0xD;// 0x1;
        //int ipj_connection_type = 0;

        RFIDMain r = new RFIDMain();

        PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
        //Pointer ipj_reader_identifier = pref.getPointer();

        r.rlib = (rfidlib) Native.loadLibrary("rfidlib", rfidlib.class);
        r.ipj_iri_device = new ipj_iri_device();
        r.ipj_action = new ipj_action();
        r.errorStatus = r.rlib.start(r.ipj_iri_device, r.ipj_action);
    }
```

Below shown is my interface in Java.

```
public interface rfidlib extends Library {

    public ipj_error initialize_iri_device(ipj_iri_device iriDevice);

    public ipj_error connect_device(ipj_iri_device iri_device, Pointer ipj_read_identifier, int ipj_connectionType,
        ipj_connection_params params);

    public ipj_error disconnect_device(ipj_iri_device iri_device);

    public ipj_error receive(ipj_iri_device iri_device);

    public ipj_error reset(ipj_iri_device iri_device, ipj_reset_type reset_type);

    public ipj_error set(ipj_iri_device iri_device, ipj_key key, int bank_index, int value_index, int value);

    public ipj_error set_value(ipj_iri_device iri_device, ipj_key key, int value);

    public ipj_error get(ipj_iri_device iri_device, ipj_key key, int bank_index, int value_index, IntByReference value);

    public ipj_error get_value(ipj_iri_device iri_device, ipj_key key, IntByReference value);

    public ipj_error start(ipj_iri_device iri_device, ipj_action action);

    public ipj_error stop(ipj_iri_device iri_device, ipj_action action);
}
```

Why am I getting this exception? Please advice.

Comment: Have you compared `MyStructure.size()` (Java) to `sizeof(mystruct)` (native)?  If your native structure has no alignment or padding, you'll need to set the structure alignment option accordingly.

Comment: You should also check whether `RFID_API` is defined to include `stdcall`, which is quite common on windows.  Calling with the wrong calling convention can often result in a memory fault.

Comment: You should also include what your `ipj_action` type definition looks like.  Personally, I'd just use `int` (versus `IntegerType` or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the `getFieldOrder()` method of your structure appropriatly. It should look similar to this:

```
@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("reader_context", "reader_identifier", "receive_timeout_ms", ..... );
}
```

All fields have to be listed in the correct order. Also, all fields which currently have `default` visibility, have to be made `public`!

Also, your main java class RFIDMain is not in any state it could possibly work. It looks like you are trying to apply C++ semantics on a java program - this will not work. Some hints:

- avoid using static where you can. Instead, create local variables or non-static members.
- give your members a appropriate visibility. The default is often not what you want.
- There is no RAII! By declaring variables, they are initialized with null. You have to call a constructor explicitly to initialize the variable with an object.
- You have many unused variables. You initialize them, but you are not using them - they won't magically be used at the right spots. Be sure to use them where needed!

Comment: I have made the provided suggestions but the code still throws a null pointer exception now. " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException " This structure has no values assigned to the variables as this is passed to the C code to be filled in by it. I can't figure out why the null pointer exception is coming. When I remove the Structure and use a ByteBuffer instead, I don't get any exceptions. But I don't think I am supposed to use a ByteBuffer here. Clearly there is something wrong with the structure. Please advice.